# Leaflet Geocoder restrict results by Country

Tags: javascript, geocoding, leaflet

I am using the Leaflet plugin leaflet-control-geocoder found here: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder

My aim is to restrict the results by country = UK and city = london.

My current code which works fine but am getting results also from outside UK

```
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder({position:'topleft', geocode:'countrycodes=gb'});
geocode.addTo(map);
```

The geocode uses Nominatim to respond to geocoding queries. Not sure why its not working

Answer (score 2):

The way i have restrict country

```
 var options = {
        position: 'topright',
        geocoder: new L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({
            geocodingQueryParams: {
                "countrycodes": "gb"
            }
        })
    };

   var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder(options).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to write `L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({position:'topleft', geocode:'countrycodes=gb'})` to specify that you're using Nominatim.

That is what they do in the demo at this link: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder/blob/master/demo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use geocoder without `nominatim()`, then you can do the country filter as the following. The loops are ugly I know, it could be better solved with mapping to object. It's just for demonstration.

```js
geocoder.query('pass-a-search-string-criteria', showResult);

function showResult(err, data) {
  if (!map) {
    map = L.mapbox.map('your-map-id', 'mapbox.streets');
  }
  if (data.lbounds) {                          
    [].slice.call(data.results.features).forEach(function(place){
      [].slice.call(place.context).some(function(ccode, i) {
          if (i === 3 && ccode.short_code ==='gb') {
               console.log(place.place_name);
          }
      });
    });
    map.fitBounds(data.lbounds);
  } else if (data.latlng) {
    map.setView([data.latlng[0], data.latlng[1]], 13);
  }
}
```